# Mysql & Django - UniqueConstraint not enforced

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, unique-constraint

I have the following model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    objects = AQueryManager() //fills the table with values
    b = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'maker_A'
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                Lower('b'),
                name='b uniqueness'
            )]
```

I want to make the column "b" unique with the functionality lower, it works locally with sqllite db but does not work on MySQL, Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks a lot!

I looked everywhere but couldn't find a reason. It looks like it should work

Answer (score 0):

SQLlite and MySQL handle case sensitivity differently in unique constraints.
to fix you can add the collation attribute to the field in your model,for example **utf8_general_ci** collation.

```
class A(models.Model):
    objects = AQueryManager()
    b = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, db_collation='utf8_general_ci')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'maker_A'
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['b'],
                name='b_uniqueness'
            )]
```

Comment: The collation was added to the ddl also in the way I used the constraint (`b` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL) but no index was created and the constraint was not applied :( Do you have any idea?